# Change handlers in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For a while a would like to start using **react function components** with react hooks instead of **class extending react component**, but there is one thing which discourages me. Here is an example from very first intro of react hooks:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Row from './Row'

export default function Greeting(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');

  function handleNameChange(e) {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <Row label="Name">
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={handleNameChange}
        />
      </Row>
    </section>
  )
}
```

There is a `handleNameChange` declaration used as a change handler for input. Let's imagine that `Greeting` component updates really really frequently because of some reason. Does change handle initialize every time on every render? From JavaScript aspect of view how bad is that?

Comment: There was an error in my answer, helpfully pointed out by Richard Matsen. I've fixed it, you might want to give the updated version a read. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Actually I was already satisfied with yours and @dan-prince answer in the beginning. After what I read I understand that initializing functions as in my example is not that painfully bad because JavaScript can handle it quite well, but if I am concerned or if I have components which updates a lot, then I should use `useCallback`. Is that right?

Comment: Probably, yeah. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does change handle initialize every time on every render?

Yes. That's one reason for the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook.

> From JavaScript aspect of view how bad is that?

Fundamentally, it's just creating a new object. The function object and the underlying function code are not the same thing. The underlying code of the function is only parsed once, usually into bytecode or a simple, quick version of compilation. If the function is used often enough, it'll get aggressively compiled.

So creating a new function object each time creates some memory churn, but in modern JavaScript programming we create and release objects **all the time** so JavaScript engines are highly optimized to handle it when we do.

But using `useCallback` avoids unnecessarily recreating it *(well, sort of, keep reading)*, by only updating the one we use when its dependencies change. The dependencies you need to list (in the array that's the second argument to `useCallback`) are things that `handleNameChange` closes over that can change. In this case, `handleNameChange` doesn't close over anything that changes. The only thing it closes over is `setName`, which React guarantees won't change (see the "Note" on [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)). It does use the value from the input, but it receives the input via the arguments, it doesn't close over it. So for `handleNameChange` you can leave the dependencies blank by passing an empty array as the second argument to `useCallback`. (At some stage, there may be something that detects those dependencies automatically; for now, you declare them.)

The keen-eyed will note that even with `useCallback`, you're *still* creating a new function every time (the one you pass in as the first argument to `useCallback`). But `useCallback` will return the previous version of it instead if the previous version's dependencies match the new version's dependencies (which they always will in the `handleNameChange` case, because there aren't any). That means that the function you pass in as the first argument is immediately available for garbage collection. JavaScript engines are **particularly** efficient at garbage collecting objects (including functions) that are created during a function call (the call to `Greeting`) but aren't referenced anywhere when that call returns, which is part of why `useCallback` makes sense. (Contrary to popular belief, objects can and are created on the stack when possible by modern engines.) Also, reusing the same function in the props on the `input` may allow React to more efficiently render the tree (by minimizing differences).

The `useCallback` version of that code is:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react' // ***
import Row from './Row'

export default function Greeting(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');

  const handleNameChange = useCallback(e => {        // ***
    setName(e.target.value)                          // ***
  }, [])                                             // *** empty dependencies array

  return (
    <section>
      <Row label="Name">
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={handleNameChange}
        />
      </Row>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Here's a similar example, but it also includes a second callback (`incrementTicks`) that *does* use something it closes over (`ticks`). Note when `handleNameChange` and `incrementTicks` actually change (which is flagged up by the code):

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

let lastNameChange = null;
let lastIncrementTicks = null;

function Greeting(props) {
    const [name, setName]   = useState(props.name  || "");
    const [ticks, setTicks] = useState(props.ticks || 0);
  
    const handleNameChange = useCallback(e => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }, []); // <=== No dependencies
    if (lastNameChange !== handleNameChange) {
        console.log(`handleNameChange ${lastNameChange === null ? "" : "re"}created`);
        lastNameChange = handleNameChange;
    }
    const incrementTicks = useCallback(e => {
        setTicks(ticks + 1);
    }, [ticks]); // <=== Note the dependency on `ticks`
    if (lastIncrementTicks !== incrementTicks) {
        console.log(`incrementTicks ${lastIncrementTicks === null ? "" : "re"}created`);
        lastIncrementTicks = incrementTicks;
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
          <div>
              <label>
                  Name: <input value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
              </label>
          </div>
          <div>
              <label>
                  Ticks: {ticks} <button onClick={incrementTicks}>+</button>
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting name="Mary Somerville" ticks={1} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When you run that, you see that `handleNameChange` and `incrementTicks` were both created. Now, change the name. Notice that nothing is recreated (well, okay, the new ones aren't used and are immediately GC'able). Now click the `[+]` button next to ticks. Notice that `incrementTicks` is recreated (because the `ticks` it closes over was stale, so `useCallback` returned the new function we created), but `handleNameChange` is still the same.

Comment: I'm not convinced you need `name` as a dependency of the handler, the handler logic does not depend on the data it is handling. Certainly works without it.

Comment: Good answer wrt to principle, though. It's quite hard to find a good use-case for dependencies on `useCallback()`. I thought in this scenario to change the handler based on `title` (e.g add a 'PHD' suffix), but even that can be done by directly using `title` in the handler.

Comment: The problem with the example as given is it might encourage more complexity than is needed, i.e all handlers must depend on the data being handled.

Comment: @RichardMatsen - You're absolutely right, thanks for flagging that up. `handleNameChange` doesn't close over anything but `setName` (which React guarantees to be stable). I've updated the answer. For the example, I punted and added the usual counter thing (`ticks` in this case) alongside `name`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking strictly from a JavaScript perspective (ignoring React), defining a function inside a loop (or inside another function that's called regularly) is unlikely to become a performance bottleneck.

Take a look at these [jsperf cases](https://jsperf.com/function-declaration-vs-function-expression/15). When I run this test, the function declaration case runs at 797,792,833 ops/second. It's not necessarily a best practice either, but it's often a pattern that falls victim to premature optimization from programmers who assume that defining a function must be slow.

Now, from React's perspective. It can become a challenge for performance is when you are passing that function to child components who end up re-rendering because it's technically a new function each time. In that case it becomes sensible to reach for [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to preserve the identity of the function across multiple renders.

It's also worth mentioning that even with the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook, the function expression is still redeclared with each render, it's just that it's value is ignored unless the dependency array changes.